# SVG - Top pixels were not visible

Tags: css, svg

Using SVG as a source of my `<img>` and it is a clock having a circle and hour minute hands.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g class="sprite" id="ico-watch" transform="scale(0.03125 0.03125)">
    <path d="M512 960c-282.317 0-512-229.683-512-512s229.683-512 512-512 512 229.683 512 512-229.683 512-512 512zM512-23.040c-259.727 0-471.040 211.292-471.040 471.040 0 259.727 211.313 471.040 471.040 471.040 259.748 0 471.040-211.313 471.040-471.040 0-259.748-211.292-471.040-471.040-471.040zM790.733 748.298c8.274-7.68 8.765-20.644 1.085-28.938l-225.587-243.057c4.444-8.499 7.209-18.043 7.209-28.303 0-15.79-6.124-30.065-15.933-40.94l84.808-156.344c5.407-9.933 1.7-22.364-8.233-27.75-3.092-1.679-6.431-2.478-9.748-2.478-7.27 0-14.316 3.871-18.022 10.711l-84.808 156.324c-3.113-0.492-6.246-0.963-9.503-0.963-33.935 0-61.44 27.505-61.44 61.44s27.505 61.44 61.44 61.44c8.663 0 16.896-1.843 24.371-5.079l225.403 242.852c7.7 8.335 20.623 8.786 28.959 1.085z" fill="#000000" stroke-width="1" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**Demo:** [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uvwx1wuf/)

**Issue:** The top pixel(s) is not visible, the circle is incomplete. Adding `padding-top:10px;` dynamically works, but not when added to the SVG file itself.

Comment: Where is your css code ? you have added ".sprite" class in group element.

Comment: **padding-top:10px;** is working for me

Comment: @SayedRafeeq, I don't have a CSS part yet, the class attr is a placeholder for now.

Comment: @Thinker, `padding-top:10px;` works in jsFiddle as it inject the result dynamically. But it doesn't work outside fiddle.

Comment: Maybe not telated, but when you load an svg doc  into an html `<img>` element, you need to set absolte width and height attribute of your root svg element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `translate(0, 60)` works, you just need to reposition your svg in the viewbox.

Since your SVG was a big blank space with a small clock, I've used `width="32" height="32"` on the `<svg>` element to size the viewport

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="sprite" id="ico-watch" transform="scale(0.03125 0.03125) translate(0, 60)">
        <path d="M512 960c-282.317 0-512-229.683-512-512s229.683-512 512-512 512 229.683 512 512-229.683 512-512 512zM512-23.040c-259.727 0-471.040 211.292-471.040 471.040 0 259.727 211.313 471.040 471.040 471.040 259.748 0 471.040-211.313 471.040-471.040 0-259.748-211.292-471.040-471.040-471.040zM790.733 748.298c8.274-7.68 8.765-20.644 1.085-28.938l-225.587-243.057c4.444-8.499 7.209-18.043 7.209-28.303 0-15.79-6.124-30.065-15.933-40.94l84.808-156.344c5.407-9.933 1.7-22.364-8.233-27.75-3.092-1.679-6.431-2.478-9.748-2.478-7.27 0-14.316 3.871-18.022 10.711l-84.808 156.324c-3.113-0.492-6.246-0.963-9.503-0.963-33.935 0-61.44 27.505-61.44 61.44s27.505 61.44 61.44 61.44c8.663 0 16.896-1.843 24.371-5.079l225.403 242.852c7.7 8.335 20.623 8.786 28.959 1.085z" fill="#000000" stroke-width="1" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Not sure this is the only possible way to solve. But it saved me. Thanks

Comment: This is the easier way I know. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

The SVG it-self is off canvas.
You can fix it by redefining the canvas with a `viewBox` attribute

```css
svg {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 -70 1030 1040" width="200">
  <g class="sprite" id="ico-watch">
    <path d="M512 960c-282.317 0-512-229.683-512-512s229.683-512 512-512 512 229.683 512 512-229.683 512-512 512zM512-23.040c-259.727 0-471.040 211.292-471.040 471.040 0 259.727 211.313 471.040 471.040 471.040 259.748 0 471.040-211.313 471.040-471.040 0-259.748-211.292-471.040-471.040-471.040zM790.733 748.298c8.274-7.68 8.765-20.644 1.085-28.938l-225.587-243.057c4.444-8.499 7.209-18.043 7.209-28.303 0-15.79-6.124-30.065-15.933-40.94l84.808-156.344c5.407-9.933 1.7-22.364-8.233-27.75-3.092-1.679-6.431-2.478-9.748-2.478-7.27 0-14.316 3.871-18.022 10.711l-84.808 156.324c-3.113-0.492-6.246-0.963-9.503-0.963-33.935 0-61.44 27.505-61.44 61.44s27.505 61.44 61.44 61.44c8.663 0 16.896-1.843 24.371-5.079l225.403 242.852c7.7 8.335 20.623 8.786 28.959 1.085z"
    fill="#000000" stroke-width="1" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

But, I think there is a real problem with the SVG it-self. The circle isn't even a circle!
You could simplify it a lot, and get rid of your off-canvas problem, by recreating a clean one from scratch.

```css
svg {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200">
  <g class="sprite" id="ico-watch" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47"/>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="6" fill="black" stroke="none"/>
    <path d="M50,50 l13,-22 M50,50 l25,25"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: From your answer, I learned a step forward in viewBox usage. Thanks for that. On migrating path to circle, I have this pic(watch) as an example and I face the issue on all my SVG's. But I hope your answer will help others looking in specific for circles.